# strdup(): Confused about warnings ('implicit declaration', 'makes pointer...without a cast', memory leak)

Tags: c, gcc, valgrind, strdup

When I compile the short piece of code below (in which we define a string and then use strdup to make a copy), I get 3 warnings: 2 compiler warnings from GCC and 1 run-time warning/error from valgrind.

I suspect the memory leak error (reported by valgrind) is also related to my use of strdup, which is why I'm including the relevant output below.

What am I doing wrong?  (I'm working my way through a C book and this is how strdup is used by the author.)

---

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  char *string1 = "I love lamp";
  char *string2;

  string2 = strdup(string1);

  printf("Here's string 1: %s\n"
     "Here's string 2: %s\n",
     string1, string2);

  return 0;
}
```

---

The warnings/output:

```
dchaudh@dchaudhUbuntu:~/workspaceC/LearnCHW/Ex17_StructsPointers$ make test
cc -std=c99    test.c   -o test
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:9:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strdup’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   string2 = strdup(string1);
   ^
test.c:9:11: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   string2 = strdup(string1);
           ^
dchaudh@dchaudhUbuntu:~/workspaceC/LearnCHW/Ex17_StructsPointers$ valgrind --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full ./test
==3122== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3122== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3122== Using Valgrind-3.10.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3122== Command: ./test
==3122== 
Here's string 1: I love lamp
Here's string 2: I love lamp
==3122== 
==3122== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3122==     in use at exit: 12 bytes in 1 blocks
==3122==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 12 bytes allocated
==3122== 
==3122== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==3122==    at 0x4C2ABBD: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:296)
==3122==    by 0x4EBF2B9: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==3122==    by 0x4005A4: main (in /home/dchaudh/workspaceC/LearnCHW/Ex17_StructsPointers/test)
==3122== 
==3122== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3122==    definitely lost: 12 bytes in 1 blocks
==3122==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3122==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3122==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3122==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3122== 
==3122== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3122== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: You haven't included the relevant header for `strdup`.

Comment: He did. @OliverCharlesworth

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The C standard library does not have such function as `strdup`. Nevertheless this popular function is usually provided by standard library implementations as an extension. In GCC implementation this function is declared in `<string.h>`, which you do include.

However, when you compile your code with stricter standard settings, like `-std=c99`, the compiler hides non-standard function declarations made in standard library headers. This is what happened to `strdup` declaration in your case. The warning that you get is a typical warning that is issued when you attempt to call an undeclared function. Formally, this is an error from C99 point of view, but your compiler decided that a warning is sufficient in this case. If you remove the `-std=c99` switch from the compiler's command line, the declaration of `strdup` will become visible and the code will compile without that warning.

More technically, specifying `-std=c99` in the command line makes GCC to define `__STRICT_ANSI__` macro, which causes all non-ANSI function declarations to "disappear" from the standard headers.

The function is still present in the library, which is why your code *links* properly. Note that it does not necessarily *run* properly, since the compiler assumed that `strdup` returned an `int`, when in reality it returns a pointer.

The valgrind report is just a consequence of memory leak. `strdup` allocates memory that you are supposed to `free` yourself when you no longer need it.

Comment: Might want to add that there are valid reasons to leave freeing memory be when the program ends, but those do not apply to a beginner trying to learn the language.

Comment: +1 "Though [`strdup()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) is declared in `<string.h>`, it is *not* a standard C supplied library function." Sry, I had a hard time parsing that first sentence.

Comment: The "real" reference: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html @WhozCraig

Comment: @alk Yeah, I just grabbed the first one I found which stated the standard that specs the function (its in there, your link is to the specced standard. Thx.).

Comment: You nailed it - I made the changes and it ran without a hitch.  Regarding the '-std=c99' flag: I include it so I can use c99 syntax, e.g., for(*int i = 0*, i < n; ++i).  Is there any way for me to have my cake and eat it too?  Or is the solution simply to include the flag and ignore these types of warnings from the compiler?

Comment: @Dipak C: `-std=gnu99` will give you the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 16):

`strdup()`  isn't standard C. [It is a POSIX extension](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html).

To make [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) available even with strict C99 compliance for GCC when using the option `-std=c99` you need to `#define` at least one of the following:

```
_SVID_SOURCE || _BSD_SOURCE || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500 
  || _XOPEN_SOURCE && _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED
  || /* Since glibc 2.12: */ _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L
```

<sup>(taken from [`strdup()`'s Linux man-page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html))</sup>

by coding for example (before including `<string.h>`):

```
#define _SVID_SOURCE
```

or:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
```

Alternatively you can pass those defines via GCC's command-line as option

```
-D_SVID_SOURCE
```

or

```
-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L
```

Comment: That last "200**9**09L" is a mistake, right? I'm guessing it should be "200809L".

Comment: @hmijail Absolutely! Thanks for notifying. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

As AnT already said, when you use the flag "-std=c99" the compiler hides all non-standard function in the header "string.h"

One way to fix it is to add this line of code, at the beggining of your code (or wherever you want, as long as it is before using the strdup function)

`extern char* strdup(const char*);`

Answer (score -3):

Your compiler doesn't have a declaration of strdup, because you didn't #include any header file declaring it.

Having no declaration, the compiler guessed that strdup would return an int. You assign the result of calling strdup to a pointer variable.

Include the right header file, and your problems should at least get less.

Comment: As per the OP's sources `<string.h>` **is** included.